# How to replicate in LINQ a SQL query that uses Coalesce to pivot rows into a single column

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, coalesce

How can I achieve this functionality from SQL in LINQ? 
Here I am getting 3 SP Number to one Contract ID:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @Names = COALESCE( @Names + ', ', '') +  us.SP_NBR
FROM CAATS_ADMIN.CONTRACT_SP us
WHERE US.CNTRCT_ID='1000038'
```

Comment: I can't make sense of this query. Can you give example input and output?

Comment: This is a SQL Server trick to pivot a set of rows into a comma delimited list in a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LINQ aggregate function. You will need to retrieve the data in a SELECT to a list of strings through whatever data access mechanism you are using then you use the Aggregate like this:

```
List<string> source = GetMyData();
var b = source.Aggregate ("", 
           (current, s)=> string.Concat(current, string.Format("{0},", s)) );
```

This applies the string concatenation to every item in the sequence to build a single string.